# my javascript code runs on pc but doesn't run on android or ios

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I'm updating some fields on my webpage with dynamic content using javascript. It works perfect with all PC browsers (I tested with Firefox, IE and Chrome) but doesn't work on Android phones and iPhone. The phone displays the static content but doesn't show the values written by javascript.

could it be related to the format of the reply message for HTTP GET? I haven't included an HTTP header in the reply message, just raw data.

My js code is below:

```
function get_datetime() {
    var GetReq = false;
    var hourText = document.getElementById("hour");
    var minuteText = document.getElementById("minute");
    var dayText = document.getElementById("day");
    var monthText = document.getElementById("month");
    var yearText = document.getElementById("year");

    function GetValComplete() {
        if (GetReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (GetReq.status == 200) {
                var time = GetReq.responseText.split(";");
                hourText.value = time[0];
                minuteText.value = time[1];
                dayText.value = time[2];
                monthText.value = time[3];
                yearText.value = time[4];
            }
        }
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        GetReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        GetReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (GetReq) {
        GetReq.open("GET", "/datetime?id=" + Math.random(), true);
        GetReq.onreadystatechange = GetValComplete;
        GetReq.send(null);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

my html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9" />
<title>date-time</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datetime.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.auto-style3 {
border: 1px solid #000000;
width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="get_datetime();">
<br />
<h2><strong>date-time settings:</strong></h2>
<h2><strong></strong></h2>
<br />
<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">
<p><label for="hour">Hour</label>
<input name="hour" id="hour" class="auto-style3" type="text" /><label     for="minute">Minute</label>
<input name="minute" id="minute" class="auto-style3" type="text" /></p>
</form>
<br />
<form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="">
<label for="day">Day</label>
<input name="day" class="auto-style3" id="day" type="text" /><label     for="month">Month</label>
<input name="month" class="auto-style3" id="month" type="text" /><label     for="year">Year</label>
<input name="year" class="auto-style3" id="year" type="text" /></form>
<br />
</body></html>
```

Comment: The code works just fine on the iPhone (using `<input type=text ...>` and `onLoad='get_datetime();'`), so I suspect the issue is either the way you call it or your HTML... You may want to provide the details ...

Comment: Maybe delegating cross-browser hurdles to jQuery could solve your problem.

Comment: Use the developer console to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it was the missing HTTP header. The HTTP responses which carry the dynamic content haven't had any HTTP header. Now I added the header manually (I had to add it manually because it is a custom-made system) and it worked.

The missing header doesn't matter on PC browsers, but apparently isn't accepted by Android / iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a special character set, could this be the problem?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9" />
```

There is no reason for the closure -- try taking it out.  Like so:

```
function get_datetime() {
    var GetReq = false;

    function GetValComplete() {
        if (GetReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (GetReq.status == 200) {
                var time = GetReq.responseText.split(";");

                var hourText = document.getElementById("hour");
                var minuteText = document.getElementById("minute");
                var dayText = document.getElementById("day");
                var monthText = document.getElementById("month");
                var yearText = document.getElementById("year");

                hourText.value = time[0];
                minuteText.value = time[1];
                dayText.value = time[2];
                monthText.value = time[3];
                yearText.value = time[4];
            }
        }
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        GetReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        GetReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (GetReq) {
        GetReq.open("GET", "/datetime?id=" + Math.random(), true);
        GetReq.onreadystatechange = GetValComplete;
        GetReq.send(null);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this isn't the reason of the problem, because on some of my pages I don't have the variable definitions at the beginning and it doesn't work anyway.